# C++ Inheritance: calling overloaded base class function

Tags: c++

Can someone help me understand why the overloaded bar function doesn't work in this case?

```
  class A {
  public:
     void foo(int a) {};
     void bar(int a) {};
     virtual void bar()=0;       
  };

  class B : public A{
  public:
      virtual void bar() override {};
  };

  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      B b;
      b.foo(2); // fine
      b.bar();  // fine
      b.bar(2); // not fine
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overriding works fine, but the override **shadows** the base class function. That is, name lookup in known class B finds only the one in B, the lookup stops there. You can either use base class qualification, or a `using` declaration in B, or (ugly) manual forwarders.

Example:

```
class B
    : public A
{
public:
    using A::bar;
    virtual void bar() override {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually in the ISO C++ FAQ, with code examples

Trick is to add a

```
   public: 
   using A::bar;
```

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule

Comment: Well the `using` declaration is one of several practical solutions.